# I am using google bigquery and i want to delete rows having timestamp after particuler time period

Tags: google-bigquery

delete from `elaborate-howl-285701.context.expense`
where time_stamp >=  '2021-05-03 11:29:14.288066' and time_stamp <=  '2021-05-03 14:29:14.288066'

I want to delete rows having time period between mention in where clause. Every time I runs it gives error
"UPDATE or DELETE statement over table elaborate-howl-285701.context.expense would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported"

Comment: As an aside, you have a column (TIME_STAMP) that would appear to be either of type TIMESTAMP or DATE, and are comparing it to a literal character string.  It most likely should be something like "where time_stamp >= to_timestamp('2021-05-03 11:29:14.288066','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it takes [no more than 90 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) for the data to become available for copy/delete operations. Just wait a bit.